# Laravel Moving money between users

Tags: laravel

I code a script for my website

I have 2 tables, **Setting** and **transactions**

In the Setting table each user have a transfer code, I want create a page so `"A" user` come and write `"B" user` transfer code and a price so price reduce from `"A" user` and create a row in Transactions table with `"B" user_id`

How can I do this?

(internal money transfer between 2 users)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. For this transaction to be complete you will have to deduct one account and add the amount to the other users account. When that has been processed you will store the transaction information in a table like transactions table.

Read more about DB transactions from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database)

Answer (score 0):

Moving money between two accounts is a *transaction*. Such a transaction consists of two actions: debiting one account and crediting another. These actions should be stored in a *ledger*.

The act of generating and using “codes” to create a transfer is something that you’ll need to create at the application level. You could have a codes table with two columns for the users (`from_user_id` and `to_user_id` or similar) and the amount to be transferred.

How these codes are redeemed, is up to you. Just make sure to validate them!